# why mochawesome-merge is adding command path in generated ,json file?

Tags: cypress, mochawesome

when I execute command :

> npx mochawesome-merge ./cypress/report/heec-report/*.json>./cypress/report/report.json

then it generate report.json ,   but it add a line "C:\E2E_Automation\node_modules\mochawesome-merge\bin\mochawesome-merge.js? on top of generated .json file.

this is causing failure to below command with error "Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0":

> npx marge --reportDir cypress/reports ./cypress/report/report.json

How to fix this issue?